# How to slice the output of tf.train.shuffle_batch() using tf.train.range_input_producer()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow to train a Recurrent Neural Network on spectrograms of audio recordings. The data is rather big, so I want to store the data as tfrecords and feed it via an input pipeline (similar to`cifar10_input.py`). However, since my spectrograms will serve as input to an RNN they will have to be further sliced in to windows (or slices) that are`num_steps`long as, for example, in`ptb_producer`(see[`reader.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py) from tensorflow's RNN tutorial).

My question is how to do this? How do I add yet another queue that slices up the batch of spectrograms?

Each spectrogram is`num_times = 15000`long, and should be sliced up into`num_slices`slices that each are`num_steps`long.

I have tried the following:

```py
def data_producer(fname, batch_size, num_epochs):

    fname_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([fname],
                                                 num_epochs=num_epoch)
    # Read 1 spectrogram and labels
    X_alltimes, y_alltimes = read_tfrecords(fname_queue)
    # number of time-bins in X_alltimes
    num_times = 15000
    # number of frequencies in X_alltimes
    num_frequencies = 175

    # Stack batch_size spectrograms to make a batch
    X_alltimes_batch, y_alltimes_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [X_alltimes, y_alltimes],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)

    # max number of num_step windows/slices we can get from X_alltimes.
    num_slices = num_times // num_step
    # slice index
    i = tf.train.range_input_producer(
        limit=num_slices,
        shuffle=False).dequeue()

    X = tf.strided_slice(
        X_alltimes_batch,
        [0, i * num_step, 0],
        [batch_size, (i + 1) * num_step, num_frequencies],
        strides=[1, 1, 1])
    X.set_shape([batch_size, num_step, num_frequencies])

    y = tf.strided_slice(
        y_alltimes_batch,
        [0, i * num_step + 1],
        [batch_size, (i + 1) * num_step + 1],
        strides=[1, 1])
   y.set_shape([batch_size, num_step])

   return X, y

# Try to get some slices
X, y = data_producer(fname, batch_size=25, num_steps=10, num_epochs=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    # Start input enqueue threads.
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners()

    for i in range(50):
        print(sess.run([X, y]))
```

However, each call to`run()`pulls out a new batch and not a new slice. How do I step through all`num_slices`slices before getting a new batch?

Comment: I see that I was wrong about the slice index (`i`), it does indeed change. But, for each update of `i`, the batch is also updated. What I want is that `i` runs from `0` to `num_slices - 1` before `X_alltimes_batch` is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that the proper way to doing this is to use `tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states()` or `tf.contrib.training.SequenceQueueingStateSaver()`.
From the tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.training/splitting_sequence_inputs_into_minibatches_with_state_saving): *Use SequenceQueueingStateSaver or its wrapper batch_sequences_with_states if you have input data with a dynamic primary time / frame count axis which you'd like to convert into fixed size segments during minibatching, and would like to store state in the forward direction across segments of an example.*

A simple example:

```
def load_sequences(fname):

   N = 10  # number of sequences
   fname_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([fname])
   X, y, n_times, n_freqs = read_tfrecords(fname_queue)

   context = {}
   context['n_times'] = n_times
   context['n_freqs'] = n_freqs
   context['length'] = X.get_shape()[0].value

   sequences = {'inputs': X,
                'labels': y}

   # i only provided a unique number for key
   i = tf.train.range_input_producer(limit=N, shuffle=True).dequeue()
   key = string_ops.string_join(['key_', string_ops.as_string(i)])

   return key, context, sequences


def test_sequence_loader(fname):

   batch_sz=2
   num_unroll=15
   n_threads=1
   initial_states =  {"state": tf.zeros(batch_sz, dtype=tf.float32)}

   key, context, sequences = load_sequences(fname, Nepoch=1)

   batch = tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states(
       input_key=key,
       input_sequences=sequences,
       input_context=context,
       input_length=tf.cast(context['length'], tf.int32),
       initial_states=initial_states,
       num_unroll=num_unroll,
       batch_size=batch_sz,
       num_threads=n_threads,
       capacity=batch_sz * 50)

   inputs = batch.sequences["inputs"]
   labels = batch.sequences["labels"]
   state = batch.state("state")  
   state_update = batch.save_state("state", state + 1) # necessary to proceed through the slices.

   input_slice = tf.split(value=inputs, num_or_size_splits=num_unroll, axis=1)
   label_slice = tf.split(value=labels, num_or_size_splits=num_unroll, axis=1)

   with tf.Session() as sess:
       sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
       sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
       # Start input enqueue threads.
       threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners()

       for i in range(50):
           # the state has to be updated in order to move through slices
           [X, y, _, _] = sess.run([input_slice, label_slice, state, state_update])
           print('len(X):', len(X), 'X[0].shape:', X[0].shape, 'len(y): ', len(y))
```

Output:

```
len(X): 15 X[0].shape: (2, 1, 175) len(y):  15
len(X): 15 X[0].shape: (2, 1, 175) len(y):  15
...
```